# Salt-Stack exclude minions from salt '*' state.apply in top.sls

Tags: salt-stack

Is there a way to exclude minions from being targeted even if I run `salt '*' state.apply` on CLI?

Ideally the exclusion should be declared somewhere in top.sls

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use compound matching. Targetting all the minions for the webserver states except `minion_id_1` can be done like this.

```
base:
  'not minion_id_1':
    - match: compound
    - webserver
```

Documentation on compound matching can be found here: [docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/topics/targeting/compound.html](http://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/topics/targeting/compound.html)

Answer (score 4):

From CLI, you can exclude minion as follows,

```
salt -C 'not minion-id' test.ping
```

Above pattern is available since version `2015.8.0`. If you are using older version then,

```
salt -C '* and not minion-id' test.ping
```

Please read more about [Compound matchers here](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/topics/targeting/compound.html).